# How to find the standard deviation?

Tags: standard-deviation, proportion

I need help figuring out the standard deviation if 6% is the "mean" than how many Standard deviation away is 9%. "is it 0.5 std dev away or more?"

A goal for female population is set at 6% (goal set by outside vendor based on market availability) and the company has 9% female population (599 female out of 6550) so how many SDs is 9% from 6%?

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what you mean by the last paragraph?

Comment: @mdewey it is just an example as we have 599 female out of 6550 people and that percentage is 9% but there is a set goal of how many females they should have which is 6% so I need to find out how many Std Devs is 9% from 6%.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 2):

You want to calculate the z-score corresponding to $\hat{p}=0.09$ (sample proportion) and $p_0=0.06$ (true proportion). This gives you the number of standard deviations away an observation is from $p_0=0.06$. What is the standard error for the sample proportion?

Comment: I dont know the standard error for the sample proportion.599/6550